# Segment a polygon with pixel data and fit best line

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, python-imaging-library, polygons

I am working with a jpeg of [two intersecting pentagons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XZP3a.jpg). I have converted the image into pixel data with PIL, but I am having trouble with segmenting each line segment of the polygon. I want to place a best fit line on each segment to work with angles and segments to compare other figures to. I am currently setting a left/right/low/high bound to capture each segment. It works, but does not capture every pixel. There has to be a better way to separate the segments or to analyze the polygons. Any help or direction is appreciated.

```
img = Image.open(path)

data = img.getdata()
height, width = img.size

pixelList = []
pix = img.load()

for x in range(height):
    for y in range(width):
        pixelList.append((x, y, pix[x,y]))

black_coords = []
x_coords = []
y_coords = []

for i in pixelList:
    if i[2][0] < 50:
        black_coords.append((i[0],i[1]))
        x_coords.append(i[0])
        y_coords.append(i[1])

plt.scatter(x_coords,y_coords)

def segment_bound(left_bound, right_bound, low_bound, high_bound):
    segX = []
    segY = []
    for i in black_coords:
        if i[0] > left_bound and i[0] < right_bound and i[1] > low_bound and 
i[1] < high_bound:
            segX.append(i[0])
            segY.append(i[1])
    return segX, segY
```

this is the code for each segment it is tedious but works

```
seg1X, seg1Y = segment_bound(147.4, 285.7, 305, 345)
startline = min(seg1X)
endline = max(seg1X)
p_coeff = np.polyfit(seg1X, seg1Y, 1)
p = np.poly1d( p_coeff )
x = np.linspace( startline, endline)
seg1m, seg1b = list(p)
```

Comment: You're probably better of using an existing line-detection implementation from a computer vision library such as OpenCV.

Comment: Specifically, you should look into Hough line transforms. I personally find the implementation in scikit-image easiest to use: `skimage.transform.probabilistic_hough_line`.